# json web token malformed error in node js

Tags: node.js, angular

[image]I have tried to use jsonwebtoken in node js to signin and verify the credentials using angular and node js.

kindly inform the reason why its showing this error.

Here is my code in app.js

```
var express = require('express');
    var cors = require('cors');
    var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
    var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    var app = express();

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(cors());

function verifyToken(req,res,next)
{
    if(!req.headers.authorization)
    {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
    }

    var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

    if(!token)
    {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
    }

    if(token === 'null')
    {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
    }

    let payload = jwt.verify(token,'secretKey');

    if(!payload)
    {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request');
    }

    req.userId = payload.subject;

    next();
}

app.get('/dashboard',verifyToken,function(req,res){
    let events = [];
    res.json(events);
});
```

Comment: can you share the error? Also, are you able to decode it?

Comment: what is sent with the token so you had to split it ?!
also what is the error that you get ?!

Comment: i have added the error check that image

Answer (score 0):

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const keys = require('../keys');

module.exports = (req,res,next)=>{
    try
    {
        const token = req.headers.token
        const decodetoken = jwt.verify(token, keys.jwt_token_key)
        //console.log(decodetoken)
        if(token)
        {
            req.username = decodetoken.username
            req.id = decodetoken.id
            next()
        }else{
            res.status(401).json({
                'response_message':'token not present'
            });
        }
        
    }catch(err){
        res.status(401).json({
            'response_message':'You are not authenticated'
        });
    }
}
```

try using this middleware

Comment: what is key here

Answer (score 0):

I have used decode instead of verify its working

```
let payload = jwt.decode(token,'secretKey');
```